# IntelliJ IDEA and PlayFramework modules

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

After a lot of good comment about IDEA, I decided to give it a try. I downloaded the Community Edition and would like to use it for PlayFramework development.

I have followed official documentation and some other information gathered around, but I have not succeeded completely. When using a project with differents (play) modules, the different classes are not found.

For example when using Secure module, IDEA keeps complaining about not finding Secure.class. It has to be a classpath issue. I tried to attach Java source & classes ($PLAY/modules/secure/) in module settings (F4), class is still not found. Did I miss something?

BTW, I have done a play dependencies and play idealize, which seems to add another module Secure into project in IDEA.

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm, totally unaware for what reason, but it works again. Is there any cache system you have to clean sometimes?

Comment: Hmm that's odd.  I usually just do play deps --sync then play idealize.  Try to do a play clean then deps then idealize.  See if that does anything different.  Also you may have to refresh the project by closing it and opening it back up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to run the following:

```
play deps
play idealize
```

This forces the IDEA .iml project file to be refreshed with the updated class path entries for the new module (in this case Secure).

Comment: Let's add that it is better to use `play deps --sync`in order to remove all unnecessary libs.

Comment: Helpful! But for play 2  it's

play dependencies
play idea

Comment: To make mseo's comment a little bit more clear you have to execute `play dependencies` and then execute `play idea`. This creates all the necessary modules and submodules for the intellij project

Answer (score 0):

A issue I came across using IntelliJ and Playframework.

- The `log4j.properties` file or `log4j.xml` file are not in classpath by default. You have to add the `conf` as a source folder in module settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Secure module you have created in IDEA as a dependency to the main application module:

1. Go to File -> Project Structure
2. Choose the main module
3. Choose the Dependencies tab
4. Click Add -> Module Dependency
5. Choose the IDEA Module you created for the Play Secure module

Also make sure you have the correct source path selected for the Secure module in IDEA.

Comment: That is exactly what `play dependencies` is doing.